# How to query PointField - MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I was trying to update `PointField` in my `flask` app with `upsert_one`. But it always inserts new document. I know the problem is with the query which I'm passing.

Below is my model.

```
class Location(db.Document):
    location_name = db.StringField(required=True)
    geoCoords = db.PointField()
```

And the update query.

```
Location.objects(geoCoords=loc["geoCoords"]).upsert_one(location_name=loc["location_name"], geoCoords=loc["geoCoords"])
#loc["geoCoords"] = [77.6309395,12.9539974]
```

I also tried running `get`. But I'm getting the error message `"Location matching query does not exist."` for the below query.

```
loc = Location.objects(geoCoords=[77.6309395,12.9539974]).get()
```

I have following entries in my `location` collection.

```
> db.location.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59c5019727bae70ad3259e67"), "geoCoords" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 77.6309395, 12.9539974 ] }, "location_name" : "Bengaluru" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59c5022d27bae70ad3259ea2"), "geoCoords" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 77.6309395, 12.9539974 ] }, "location_name" : "Bengaluru" }
>
```

I couldn't find any related information on querying the `PointFiled`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to my question. I think there is no way to get the exact points like I have mentioned in the question.

The nearest method works here is to use `__near` selector. This accepts the range in `meters`. So, you can give closest range query as per your requirement.

In my case, I gave 100 meters. Which is fine for me.

Example:

```
Location.objects(geoCoords__near=thelocation["geoCoords"], geoCoords__max_distance=100).upsert_one(location_name=thelocation["location_name"], geoCoords=thelocation["geoCoords"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Location.objects(geoCoords="...").update(location_name=loc["location_name"], geoCoords=loc["geoCoords"])
```

Comment: `upsert_one` is not working because `Location.objects(geoCoords=loc["geoCoords"])` returns `Location matching query does not exist.`. So, same for the `update` also.